# How To: PHP + Javascript Pop-up Window

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I have the following code that gives me a list of items on the front-end, but I want those links to open in a new pop up window. Is there a way I can do this? 
Thank you.

```
echo '<div class="item_row_header">';

    for($i=0;$i<count($this->fields);$i++)  {
        echo '<div class="item_cell jdheader'.$this->fields[$i]->cssclass.'">';

        //to display the header with/without sorting option

        if(in_array($this->fields[$i]->type, array(10,11,12,13)))

            echo $this->fields[$i]->name;

        else

            echo JHTML::_('jdgrid.sort', $this->fields[$i]->name, 'field_'.$this->fields[$i]->id, @$this->cparams->filter_order_Dir, @$this->cparams->filter_order );

        echo '</div>';

    }

    echo '<div class="clr"></div></div>';

    }

echo '<div class="itemlist itemlist_type'.$this->type->id.'">';

if(count($this->items)) {

    //all the item list part display here

    for($i=0;$i<count($this->items);$i++)   {

        $item =  $this->items[$i];

        require(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'default_item.php');

    }
```

Here is what I get on the front-end with the code above:

```
 <div class="item_row_header">
  <div class="item_cell jdheader"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sort" class='field_70 desc' title="Clique para ordenar por coluna">Título</a></div>
  <div class="item_cell jdheader">Fotos</div>
  <div class="item_cell jdheader"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sort" class='field_63 desc' title="Clique para ordenar por coluna">Cidade</a></div>
  <div class="item_cell jdheader"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sort" class='field_64 desc' title="Clique para ordenar por coluna">Estado</a></div>
  <div class="item_cell jdheader"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sort" class='field_60 desc' title="Clique para ordenar por coluna">Tipo do Imóvel</a></div>
  <div class="item_cell jdheader"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="sort" class='field_67 desc' title="Clique para ordenar por coluna">Valor R$</a></div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="itemlist itemlist_type15">
  <div class="item_row_bg featured itemrow_type15">
    <div class="item_content">
      <div class="item_cell "><a href="/joomla/temporada/imoveis/itens/ver/temporada-destaque">Temporada Destaque</a></div>
      <div class="item_cell "><img src="http://mysite.com.br/joomla/images/joomd/thumbs/1350654862temporada-destaque.jpg" alt="Fotos" /></div>
      <div class="item_cell ">Exemplo de Cidade</div>
      <div class="item_cell ">São Paulo</div>
      <div class="item_cell ">Casa</div>
      <div class="item_cell ">600</div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item_row itemrow_type15">
    <div class="item_content">
      <div class="item_cell "><a href="/joomla/temporada/imoveis/itens/ver/temporada">Temporada</a></div>
      <div class="item_cell "><img src="http://mysite.com.br/joomla/images/joomd/thumbs/1350654792temporada.jpg" alt="Fotos" /></div>
      <div class="item_cell ">Exemplo de Cidade</div>
      <div class="item_cell ">São Paulo</div>
      <div class="item_cell ">Casa</div>
      <div class="item_cell ">800</div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is how I solved it:

I opened the default_item.php and found this:

```
if($j==0)   {

echo '<a href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_joomd&view=item&layout=detail&typeid='.$item->typeid.'&id='.$item->id).'">';

echo $this->field->displayfieldvalue($item->id, $this->fields[$j]->id, true);

echo '</a>';
```

}

Then I could call the pop up using jQuery [http://swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html][1]

Here is how my working code looks like now:

```
echo '<a class="propriedade" href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_joomd&view=item&layout=detail&typeid='.$item->typeid.'&id='.$item->id).'">';
```

Thank you all so much for the help.

Comment: `target="_blank"` in your `<a>` tags.

Comment: @Brad this won't work in all browsers, a lot will open in a new tab where as the question specified a new window, see my answer for specifications

Comment: what you need to know is that PHP is used only to generate HTML.. you don't use php to open a window... you use HTML... PHP has to do with server side...

Comment: Hi mah2602 could you add a sample of the resulting html?
Since you wrote pop up window i assume that you are talking about a javascript pop up window (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html).  If you want the link to open an new browser window see the answer below (<a href .. target="_blank") or do you want something like a modal window (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)?

Comment: Yes it must be a pop up window, because it's a real estate site and the window would open a listing.

Comment: @pathurs, It works plenty well enough.  Perhaps some of us don't want your sites opening up things in new windows.  Don't force stuff upon users unless you have a good reason.

Comment: @Brad, I think you're right, but unfortunately this website isn't for me, it's for a client that wants all listings in a new pop up window so consumers would compare between options.. what can I say? I've tried.

Answer (score 3):

As Alex noted, this isn't possible with just PHP. PHP is a server-side language that happens before the page is loaded. You can achieve this with HTML and JavaScript.

You should look into the JavaScript function `open()` which allows you to open a new window with an exact width/height and URL specified.

[Read more about open() here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

**EXAMPLE CODE :**

```
myWindow=window.open('http://google.com','','width=200,height=200')
```

This will open Google in a new window with dimensions of 200x200 pixels

To use this code, you must insert this in either a `<script>` tag or in an external JavaScript file. I suggest using this as a function like so:

```
function newWindow(url, width, height)
{
    myWindow=window.open(url,'','width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
}
```

You can then call this with:

```
newWindow('http://google.com', 200, 200)
```

you can implement this in your code with the `onCLick` attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="newWindow('http://google.com', 200, 200)">Click Me</a>
```

[Demo of my function with HTML and JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/RwPkV/)

The reason I suggest this function is that using the `target="_blank"` attribute on some browsers just opens in a new tab, which you can use, but I assumed you wanted a whole new window

Now that you have added some code to your question, I can see you have a lot of list items, you can simple add an anchor tag to make my function work, example:

```
<div class="item_cell "><img src="http://alii.com.br/joomla/images/joomd/thumbs/1350654792temporada.jpg" alt="Fotos" /></div>
<div class="item_cell ">Exemplo de Cidade</div>
<div class="item_cell ">São Paulo</div>
<div class="item_cell ">Casa</div>
<div class="item_cell ">800</div>
```

would become:

```
<div class="item_cell "><a href="#" onclick="newWindow(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT)"><img src="http://alii.com.br/joomla/images/joomd/thumbs/1350654792temporada.jpg" alt="Fotos" /></a></div>
<div class="item_cell "><a href="#" onclick="newWindow(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT)">Exemplo de Cidade</a></div>
<div class="item_cell "><a href="#" onclick="newWindow(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT)">São Paulo</a></div>
<div class="item_cell "><a href="#" onclick="newWindow(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT)">Casa</a></div>
<div class="item_cell "><a href="#" onclick="newWindow(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT)">800</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a beginner with PHP, where exactly do I insert this code on the one I posted? Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much for you support! There aren't any `<a href="#">item link</a>` on my code, the links for the items are generated only on the front-end I think. So is there a way I can insert the onClick function anywhere on the code I posted so that every link gets this function?

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample of these links you talk about?

Comment: Sorry, I've included more of the PHP and the resulting HTML now.

Comment: The problem is that the `<div class="item_cell "><a href="#">800</a></div>`only appears on the front-end, I can't edit it because the only way I could get this HTML code was opening my page and getting its souce code on Chrome. All I have on the back-end is the PHP code :(

Comment: wiw PHP you can use echo to add this code, IE: <div class="item_cell "><?PHP echo'<a href="#" onclick="newWindow(URL, WIDTH, HEIGHT)">';?>800</a></div>

Comment: `//all the item list part display here

    for($i=0;$i<count($this->items);$i++)   {

        $item =  $this->items[$i];

        require(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'default_item.php');

    }` where can I add the echo here?

Comment: I am not able to help you with this, because you are adding another PHP file to this file, you should probably ask a new question about adding this

Comment: I will look for this and if I manage to have success I'll post the result here. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: @mah2602 If this is the right answer, would you mind clicking the green tick? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add target="_blank" in tour  tag or use window.open method.

```
e.g.: 
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
or
<script>window.open('http://google.com','','width=200,height=200'); </script>
```

Comment: This is an exact copy my my answer but very simplified, you obviously stole the code from me as well